# How to display text on the second activity

Tags: android, android-intent

So the first activity asks user to click on one out of the 3 buttons, each button represents a color. I have created the second activity and accepted value of the button clicked. I used a if loop to match the value of button, if the value of button matches with a color, it should display a string "You have chose (Color)". However, I am not sure about the parameters I have passed via intent object. can anyone help? and yeah, I am a noob, just started out to learn Android.

```
package org.example.helloandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String EXTRA_MESSAGE= null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


/**   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
              .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
             .commit();
    }

**/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void gotoActivity(View v) {

    Button b= (Button)v;
    String message= b.getText().toString();

        if (message=="red") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "You have chose RED ");
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        if (message=="green") {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this, ColorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "You have chose GREEN!");
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        else {
            Intent intent= new Intent (this, ColorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "You have chose BLUE");
            startActivity(intent);

        }


}
```

}

Here is the code for second activity- ColorActivity

```
package org.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ColorActivity extends Activity {

String EXTRA_MESSAGE= "message";
TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color_activity);
    mTextview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE"));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make your second activity like this:
Make sure that you set your String value `EXTRA_MESSAGE` to some value

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mTextview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE"));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it just shows a blank activity without any text when I click any button on the first activity. But I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you haven't assigned `EXTRA_MESSAGE`. Change this line in `MainActivity`...

```
String EXTRA_MESSAGE= null;
```

...to...

```
String EXTRA_MESSAGE= "message";
```

Also, add the exact same line to your second `Activity`.

Second, you can't compare strings using `==` you have to use `equals(...)` method. Example...

```
if (message=="red")
```

...should be...

```
if (message.equals("red"))
```

Other than that just follow the format described by AndroidWarrior to get the extra from the `Intent` used to start your second `Activity`.

Comment: I used your technique too. The app runs but doesn't display any text in the second activity. But I really appreciate you taking time to explain the code. I will definitely go through the resource you provided. Thanks!

Comment: @user3722881 : This really shouldn't be so difficult - it's one of the basic mechanisms you'll need to start a new `Activity` and pass data to it. Edit your question and add the code for the second `Activity`.

Comment: I am sorry but I just started out Android Programming, I have added the code for second activity.